# Is it possible to view Hindi characters in the git bash console, or any console that I can run karma test runner from?

Tags: utf-8, cmd, msysgit, git-bash

Is there a way I can view Hindi characters in the console while running karma? I'm doing string comparison tests and the tests themselves work but I need to be able to see the characters in the console or the tests aren't that helpful to me. At present I get either a ? or an empty box instead of "क​"

I've tried running them on git bash,cmd and I installed msysGit but none render the character properly. As you can probably tell I'm a complete console noob so I'm a bit over my head on this. All help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Not found a solution but a work around was to use the karma-html-reporter plugin which renders the charters correctly in the browser. Guess this is pretty obscure problem but I'll leave it on-line anyway just in case.